# Send partial of FTP stream to php://output

Tags: php, ftp, stream, partial

I have a PHP-server that serves audio-files by streaming them from an FTP-server not publicly available.

After sending the approriate headers, I just stream the file to the client using [ftp_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) like this:

```
ftp_get($conn, 'php://output', $file, FTP_BINARY);
```

For reasons that has to do with `Range` headers, I must now offer to only send a part of this stream:

```
$start = 300; // First byte to stream
$stop = 499; // Last byte to stream (the Content-Length is then $stop-$start+1)
```

I can do it by downloading the entire content temporarily to a file/memory, then send the desired part to the output. But since the files are large, that solution will cause a delay for the client who has to wait for the file to first be downloaded to the PHP-server before it even starts to download to the client.

**Question:**

How can I start streaming to `php://output` from an FTP-server as soon as the first `$start` bytes have been discarded and stop streaming when I've reached the '$stop' byte?

Comment: `ftp_nb_get()`, it's last parameter `$resumepos` and `ftp_nb_continue()` might perhaps be of use.

Comment: @user555 I had missed $resumepos! Yes, it surely helps me to handle where I start from. It doesn't allow me to download a certain number of bytes though.

Comment: In the `while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA)` loop maybe you could count the received bytes somehow, however the PHP docs don't mention how many bytes are downloaded on every `ftp_nb_continue()`. If I had to guess by looking at the FTP extension [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.c) I would say that `ftp_nb_continue()` downloads as many bytes as `FTP_BUFSIZE` is set to, default being 4096. For full control I think it would be best to role your own FTP client in PHP, using `REST` and count the bytes received.

Comment: @user555 I was able to make it work :) . You can see my answer on how I did it. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using PHP's [FTP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) (eg. `ftp_get`), it is possible to open a stream using PHP's built-in [FTP wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php).

The following code would stream parts of an FTP-file to `php://output`:

```
$start = 300; // First byte to stream
$stop = 499; // Last byte to stream
$url = "ftp://username:password@server.com/path/file.mp3";

$ctx = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('resume_pos' => $start)));
$fin = fopen($url, 'r', false, $ctx);
$fout = fopen('php://output', 'w');

stream_copy_to_stream($fin, $fout, $stop-$start+1);

fclose($fin);
fclose($fout);
```

While `stream_copy_to_stream` has an `$offset` parameter, using it resulted in an error because the stream was not seekable. Using the context option `resume_pos` worked fine however.